# Android webview with webGL

Tags: javascript, android, webview

i am trying to find it a way from last few hours and couldn't done.

**Issue:** I have one html page and a webGL file(three.js file). I need to open this html file in Android Webview. WebView is failed to load the html page.

Below is the code that i have tried

```
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Android");
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
    });
 webView.loadUrl("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/index.html");
```

I had placed all my resources inside sdcard.

**Error log:**

```
 "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined", source:     file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/all.min.js (17)
 "THREE.WebGLRenderer", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/all.min.js (11)
 "THREE.WebGLRenderer: OES_texture_float extension not supported.", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/all.min.js (12)
 "THREE.WebGLRenderer: OES_texture_float_linear extension not supported.", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/all.min.js (12)
 "THREE.WebGLRenderer: OES_texture_half_float extension not supported.", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/all.min.js (12)
 "THREE.WebGLRenderer: OES_texture_half_float_linear extension not supported.", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/all.min.js (12)
 "THREE.WebGLRenderer: ANGLE_instanced_arrays extension not supported.", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/all.min.js (12)
 "THREE.WebGLRenderer: OES_element_index_uint extension not supported.", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/all.min.js (12)
 "THREE.WebGLRenderer:", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/all.min.js (12)
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/res/sky.ctm.   Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes:
  http, data, chrome, https.", source:   file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/index.html (0)
 "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of    null", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/all.min.js (16)
```

Any one can suggest me what i have to do?

Comment: you can try with webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

Comment: Thanks..but no luck..

Comment: How about fixing: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` ?

Comment: that is what i am asking? i think to remove that i need to place jQuery plugin in my html page..?

Answer (score 3):

try turning on the following settings:

```
settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

Comment: I had trouble to load textures in the WebView. Enabling this settings has worked fine for me.

Comment: doesn't help me when loadURL from internet and not locally . i cannot load and view my three.js web app inside android WebView .  android10

Comment: @HAMED were you able to resolve your issue?